# Is Parse Array implementation offers an optimization for massive amounts of data?

Tags: arrays, web-services, parse-server, bigdata

Let’s say we declare the class “Video” and one of the columns in this class is “Comments”. Each comment is a string, and the comments column is an array with many strings.

Surely it’s an architecture that works, but I’m not sure about it when it comes to a massive amount of comments per video.

Assuming that there is a client which takes 10 comments each time: `video.comments[:10]`. Do the fact that I’ve fetched the comments array also mean that the remaining tons of comments also been fetched? Or Parse made the optimization for us in order to fetch only the comments that are fetched?

What’s the solution for this kind of problems?

A solution I’ve been thinking of is to write a service on the server side which responds an array of only the required comments, but it is not useful if Parse is already offering us a solution like this in the definition of their array in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd avoid sticking those in arrays. I've worked with storing arrays of data like that on parse and it can get out of hand and inefficient fast.

I'd recommend you have a separate table that includes the video's object id, comment, user who made it, etc.  Then to get the comments you'd query on the VideoComment class, `equalTo("videoId", videoId);` and you can use the standard query pagination (skip + limit) to get the comments you need.

Comment: But then the problem of fetching lots of comments each time still occurs.
But, maybe we can `query.limit` that, and then ask the server for more comments which are not contained in the previews results with `query.notContainedIn`.
So that I think your solution will solve my problem.
Thanks a lot,
I'll update for conclusions :)

Comment: You would use query.skip and query.limit to handle pagination. I'd avoid doing the array of pointers. That gets ugly. Just use the query to fetch the first x comments for the preview if you need. You could create a function that returns you both the video object you need and the array of first x comments, without storing the array on the video objects.

Comment: Would you recommend using Relations instead of your suggestion?
As I see it, your suggestion is much easier to implement, but maybe Relation should be the right choice?

Comment: You could do this with Relations. I find relations a little harder to manage, but granted have little experience with them. One of the reasons I chose my method is that it's a more universal practice amongst databases, so it helps to "future proof" things slightly. Join Tables are common practice with DB management. Though, they can also scale pretty quick, so you have to manage your indexes on your DB efficiently if you're doing any fancy sorting or querying.